# Can't detect to surface pro 6 to be able to connect to it for miracast

Tags: miracast

Both devices are on the windows 10 may update, and they both support Miracast. Furthermore I can connect the other way without problems. They are on the same network, with connection profile set to private. I tried reinstalling wi-fi. I'd like to add, that both computers have VPN software installed, however it is turned off. Any ideas?

Comment: So you've gone to the "Connect" menu in the notification center and then selected "Projecting to this PC" and selected "Available everywhere" and not disabled? Is the second device on battery power, and/or is "This PC can only be discovered for projection on a power source" set to disabled?

Comment: Both PCs have available everywhere, they are both connected to power, and they both have the last option set to allow me to connect to it even without power.

Comment: Sounds normal. By the same network, are they both on the same Wifi network, or is one on Ethernet? Does one or the other have "internet security" software such as Norton or another firewall?

Comment: Both are on the same WIFI, neither has any security software whatsoever, except for windows defender. The one from which I am attempting to connect is a fresh windows install.